# Pass client credentials as variable to Laravel Socialite

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant

I have a Laravel application with a simple multi-tenancy set-up. Every User belongs to an Account, and the User has an AccountScope; e.g. whenever a User is queried (`User::where('name', 'like', "%query%")->get()`) they will always be filtered on the logged-in user's `account_id`.

I want to provide account admins with SSO in this application, I'm currently looking into [Microsoft's SSO](https://socialiteproviders.com/Microsoft/). If one account wants to use their company's Microsoft account's SSO, and the other Account wants to use theirs, I'll need them to provide their own `client_id`, `client_secret` and `tenant_id`.

I am trying to pass these values as variables, rather than coding them in `config/services.php`.

What I have so far is a route leading to this function:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

public function microsoftLogin()
{
    $ssoSettings = Auth::user()->account->ssoSettings;

    return Socialite::driver('microsoft')
        ->with([
            'client_id' => $ssoSettings->client_id,
            'client_secret' => $ssoSettings->client_secret,
            'redirect_uri' => config('services.microsoft.redirect'),
            'tenant_id' => $ssoSettings->tenant_id,
        ])
        ->redirect();
}
```

Which still gives me the following error:

> SocialiteProviders\Manager\Exception\MissingConfigException: Missing services entry for microsoft.client_id

And building the provider like so:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use SocialiteProviders\Microsoft\MicrosoftExtendSocialite;

public function microsoftLogin()
{
    $ssoSettings = Auth::user()->account->ssoSettings;

    return Socialite::buildProvider(MicrosoftExtendSocialite::class, [
        'client_id' => $ssoSettings->client_id,
        'client_secret' => $ssoSettings->client_secret,
        'redirect_uri' => config('services.microsoft.redirect'),
        'tenant_id' => $ssoSettings->tenant_id,
    ])->redirect();
}
```

Which gives me:

> ErrorException: Undefined array key "redirect"

The exception seems to be thrown on `'tenant_id' => $ssoSettings->tenant_id`, which is all the more strange. `config('services.microsoft.redirect')` does give me the correct string.

How can I pass the Account's SSO settings, overriding the ones from the .env/config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with [KejKej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22024455/kejkej)'s answer; Microsoft in particular just has an odd naming scheme for their socialite provider. Here's my working code:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use SocialiteProviders\Microsoft\Provider as MicrosoftProvider;

public function microsoftLogin()
{
    $ssoSettings = Auth::user()->account->ssoSettings;

    return Socialite::buildProvider(MicrosoftProvider::class, [
        'client_id' => $ssoSettings->client_id,
        'client_secret' => $ssoSettings->client_secret,
        'redirect' => config('services.microsoft.redirect'),
        'tenant_id' => $ssoSettings->tenant_id,
    ])->redirect();
}
```

There were two things I needed to fix in my code:

1. Microsoft's provider can be found in the namespace `SocialiteProviders\Microsoft\Provider`. This is the class that needs to be passed to `Socialite::buildProvider`.
2. The redirect URI's key has to be called `'redirect'`, as can be seen on [the Socialite Providers Microsoft page](https://socialiteproviders.com/Microsoft/#tenant-details)

I hope this helps future readers with a similar problem!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Socialite::buildProvider](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/5.x/src/SocialiteManager.php#LL164C21-L164C34) method. You can see how it works with the built-in providers, for example [github](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/5.x/src/SocialiteManager.php#L46)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and for providing links to the source code and everything! I tried using that function, but it throws an exception I don't know what to do with. I've updated my answer for clarity, maybe you can see if I'm using anything incorrectly?

Comment: Oh! I found it, Microsoft in particular has an odd naming scheme for their socialite provider! I got it to work now, I will add my solution as an answer!